# Handling popover menu on Swift

Tags: swift, popup

I've faced the challenge to create a "dropdown-like" menu by tapping on button.

What I've done: table view controller with nav bar and bar button, which should present a popOverMenu. For popOver I've created a new view controller.
[image]

When bar button is tapped, I call **self.present** method and this popOver appears.

```
func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {     
  let popVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popVC") as! FilterViewController
 //setting up 
 self.present(popVC, animated: true)
}
```

My question is how to get the value of selected cell and reload table view using the value of cell as a filter?
I guess I should use stuff like KVO or Combine to observe changes of selected cells, but I'm not sure...
Any ideas or medium articles are highly welcomed

Comment: I've only seen popovers on iPads. I don't think iOS natively supports popovers on iPhones. You're on your own if you really want them. My advice is, use an action sheet instead.

Comment: You want to get the selected value from the popover or you want to pass the currently selected value to the popover?

Comment: @gcharita I want to get the selected value from the popover and use this value to filter table view

Comment: @Sweeper yes I know , it isn't native. Thanks for advice